# Complexity of a Fibonacci numbers discrete log variation

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

In my work I encountered the following

FIBMOD PROBLEM:
Given $k,m$ in binary, decide if there exists $n$ such that 
$\, F_n = k \,$ (mod $m$).  
Here $F_n$ is a [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

This is a variation on the discrete log problem, but in a larger
field.  For example, let $m=p$ be a large prime.  Then the problem is
asking if there exists $n$ such that $\alpha^n + \beta^n = k$ (mod $p$),
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of  $\, x^2 - x - 1$. 
Note, however, that discrete log asks also to *find* $n$ which is potentially harder.

**Questions:**
0) Are there any references on this problem? 
1) Is this problem in NP $\cap$ co-NP?  
2) Is this problem in BQP?
3) Is there a reason to believe that FIBMOD is hard?  For example is there a way to show that FIBMOD is DISCRETE-LOG - hard?

**Note:** Fibonacci numbers mod $m$ are periodic with period $\le 6 m$, as explained in this [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) Wikipedia article.  Recall that Fibonacci numbers can be computed by taking powers of the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
F_n \\ F_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem  this implies that FIBMOD is in NP.

Comment: Not $\alpha^n+\beta^n$, but $(\alpha^n-\beta^n)/(\alpha-\beta)$.

Comment: What do you get for the question, given $k$ and $m$, decide whether there exists $n$ such that $2^n\equiv k\bmod m$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- I don't know, it's a good question.  But I am specifically interested in the Fibonacci case.

Comment: Sure, but I always look for a simpler problem. If I can't solve that, or find it already solved somewhere, it gives me some idea what I'm up against. And if I can solve it, or find it already solved somewhere, I may get some idea of how to solve the harder problem.

Comment: Over the integers Fibonacci numbers are characterized as those $n$ for which $5a^2+4$ or $5a^2-4$ is a perfect square. Alternatively, those $a$ for which $a^2-ab-b^2=\pm1$ is solvable in integers. If we had similar characterizations (mod m), then Fibmod could be reduced to "quadratic residuosity" (asking whether something is a square mod m), which in turn  is believed to be as hard as factoring (I believe it's only known that QR<Factoring).

Comment: Gjergji, this is an interesting idea. Looking at it the other way, if m=p is prime, such a characterization based on quadratic residuosity would imply that the problem is easy!

Answer (score 3):

The Binet formula for Fibonacci numbers is
$$F_n = \frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\phi - (-\phi)^{-1}},\qquad\text{where}\ \phi:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2.$$

Then the congruence $F_n\equiv k\pmod{m}$ reduces to a pair of quadratic equations (indexed by the parity of $n$):
$$z^2 - k(\phi - (-\phi)^{-1})z - (-1)^n \equiv 0\pmod{m}$$
with respect to $z:=\phi^n$. So, if we can solve these quadratic equations (which is easy if $m$ is prime), then the problem reduces to the classic discrete log problem base $\phi$ modulo $m$.

---

As for references:

Lucas sequences have been previously adopted for the needs of cryptography, providing an alternative to modular exponentiation, which most notably resulted in the LUC cryptosystem. It was however shown that *many of the supposed security advantages of LUC over cryptosystems based on modular exponentiation are either not present, or not as substantial as claimed*. You can find corresponding [references in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Applications).

For a general theory of linear recurrences over rings, see

> V. L. Kurakin, A. S. Kuzmin, A. V. Mikhalev, and A. A. Nechaev. [Linear recurring sequences over rings and modules](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02362772.pdf). *Journal of Mathematical Sciences* 76:6 (1995), 2793-2915.